# ¿Es buena idea una búsqueda palabra por palabra con mysql y php?

Tags: php, mysql

Buenas tardes!
Estoy realizando un buscador en mi tienda online de libros.
Libro tiene título, autor y editorial

```
Título             Autor                     editorial
Caperucita la Roja    Lopez Martinez, Paco   Magdalena
```

El problema que planteo es el siguiente:
Si en el buscador pongo "paco lopez martinez", usando %LIKE% no me va a encontrar el libro.

Se me ha ocurrido que para solucionar esto, puedo "trocear" la búsqueda en palabras y buscar cada palabra por separado, y luego hacer un DISTINCT para que el resultado de "paco" "lopez" y "martinez" no aparezca 3 veces...

Pero esta solución me plantea otro problema... no quiero que este libro me salga como resultado al buscar "la" (en el título del libro) porque es una palabra que me va a dar muchísimos resultados.

¿Qué me aconsejáis? ¿hago un filtrado de palabras en plan "en, la, lo, el, de"? ¿pongo un filtro para buscar solo cuando haya mas de 2-3 caracteres? ¿Qué opción puede ser mas útil al usuario? ¿Será muy lento si alguien escribe una frase de 10 palabras?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo mas efectivo sería reemplazar todos los espacios por "%". 
  De esta manera siempre que el orden sea el correcto vas a tener las respuestas..

```
Select * from tabla where titulo like "%caperucita%la%roja%";
```

Pero claro que eso no encontraría Paco Lopez Martinez, solo en el orden correcto.

Otra cosa que podes probar (si es mysql) son las full text index, son sorprendentemente rápidas (las uso en cercad de 1.000.000 de registros sin problemas).
te dejo el link : [Full Text en mysql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-search.html)

Podes reformular la pregunta si necesitas ayuda con estas búsquedas.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que la mejor opcion seria juntar la busqueda, para que fuese lo que fuese que escriba lo busque en todas las columnas, asi si busca Paco saldra lo mismo que si busca Caperucita o Magdalena:

```
SELECT * FROM tabla WHERE Título LIKE 'busqueda%' OR Autor LIKE '%busqueda%' OR editorial LIKE '%busqueda';
```

Aunque tu pregunta tiene múltiples respuestas, por que según me ha parecido a mi, todo depende un poco del punto de vista del programador, para mi esa es la mejor opción.